# Error when running batch file as a scheduled task , win server 2008

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I get a **Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** error when I try to run a batch file as a scheduled task on windows server 2008. The batch file runs a java program. when I run the batch file regularly it runs fine.

```
@ECHO OFF

:start

:playback
java -cp ../lib/*; example

:end
```

> Tue 08/30/2011  9:29:23.19:
>   C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\W bem;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   \Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\ DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Com mon7\IDE\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program F iles
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Windows
>   \System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Imaging\;C:\Pro gram Files (x86)\IBM\Director\cimom\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\ibm\ icc\cimom\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IBM\Director\bin;C:\Program Files\System Ce nter Operations
>   Manager 2007\ ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Pr ogram
>   Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\

Comment: Does the account the scheduled job runs under have the necessary permissions?

Comment: What class does it not find? If it can't find the "main" class, that means it cannot load a particular class referenced by that class (possibly including itself). You need to add all necessary references to your classpath so it can find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account that runs the batch does not seem to have its PATH configured properly. Can you add:

```
echo %DATE% %TIME%: %PATH% >> %TMP%\DebugFile.txt
```

to see that the value in path.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the CLASSPATH, not PATH - thanks to Chris! Would you please change your script to output the %CLASSPATH% and run your TASK (not the program, just execute the Task through Task Scheduler). Once you get the output, check if the folder containing the Java programs (that you are trying to run) exist in the CLASSPATH that you got output through your script. If not then you might need to modify CLASSPATH environmental variable, but do it through Control Panel - System (not through Command Line - if you do it at CommandLine, I believe it won't persist after Command Window is closed).